# как разместить блок картинок слева большая и справа 4 маленьких по высоте такой же?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
                                <div class="logo-five">
                                    <div class="logo-five-wrap">
                                        <div class=logo-1>
                                            <img  src="" alt width=100>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class=logo-group>
                                            <div class=logo-group-item>
                                                <img  src="" alt width=70 >
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=logo-group-item>
                                                <img src="" alt width=70 >
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=logo-group-item>
                                                <img src="" alt width=70 >
                                            </div>
                                            <div class=logo-group-item>
                                                <img  src="" alt width=70 >
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>    
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, к примеру таблицей:

```css
img { width: 100%; }

table {
  width: 300px; /* ширина таблицы, изменить на нужную */
}

/* table td { border: 1px solid black; } /* расскоментировать чтобы видеть границы таблицы */
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td width="*" rowspan=2><img src="https://bugaga.ru/uploads/posts/2018-03/1522426573_3.jpg" alt="1"></td>
  <td width="24%"><img src="http://static.skaip.su/img/emoticons/180x180/f6fcff/hi.gif" alt="2"></td>
  <td width="24%"><img src="http://static.skaip.su/img/emoticons/180x180/f6fcff/hi.gif" alt="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://static.skaip.su/img/emoticons/180x180/f6fcff/hi.gif" alt="4"></td>
  <td><img src="http://static.skaip.su/img/emoticons/180x180/f6fcff/hi.gif" alt="5"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*P.S.: это не единственный возможный вариант, но по мне он самый простой и быстрый. Не кидайте тапками приверженцы гридов и флексбоксов))*

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
   'header article footer'
  'header ads Nav';
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 256px);
  grid-gap: 10px;

}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#pageHeader{
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: gold; 
  
}
#mainArticle{
   grid-area: article;
   background-color: gold; 
}
#mainNav{
  grid-area: Nav;
   background-color: gold; 

}
#siteAds{
  grid-area: ads;
   background-color: gold; 
    
}
#pageFooter{
  grid-area: footer;
   background-color: gold; 
   
}
```

```html
<header id=pageHeader>
 
</header>
<article id=mainArticle>

</article>
<nav id=mainNav>

</nav>
<div id=siteAds>

</div>
<footer id=pageFooter>

</footer>
```